# What are the primary disadvantages of the following crude .NET deployment model?

Tags: .net, deployment

I'm not a .NET programmer by trade, and so while I figure out the more acceptable methods (preferably CI) of deploying .NET solutions, can someone tell me what the primary disadvantages of the following deployment procedure:

1. We have a virtual instance spun up using Windows Server 2008.
2. I have a Web site (not a virtual directory) in IIS setup that points to a folder on the C drive.
3. This folder is connected to the SVN repository, and so when we're ready for a dev deploy I simply run the update on that directory.
4. Restart IIS.

This seems to be working well, and I know the assembly is being compiled with my local workstation, which might have local configuration options, but is that really the biggest drawback? Seriously, forgive my ignorance since I'm coming from a Java background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following disadavantages come into my mind:

- You need to have direct access from the Web site to you SVN repository. That might be ok if they are part of the same network.
- If you make an "update", you will get a `.svn` subfolder in any of your subfolders on the target machine. If you want to avoid that, you could make an *export* instead of an *update*, but then next time you make an export again, any deleted files in your dev tree will stay on the production machine. That is typically not what you want. As a resort, you could first delete the destination folder completely before you make an export, if thats an option for you.
- exporting from SVN does typically involve just `copy` and `delete` commands; if there is no more "intelligence" needed for you deployment, that might be ok, but if you have to, for example, migrate config files from one release to another, or have to make a database update, then SVN is not sufficient.
- Your SVN folder structure must exactly match the needed folder structure on the target machine (most probably that's the case in your situation, otherwise you had not suggested this idea).

Answer (score 1):

Are you making use of server-side session object at all?  Those session objects may be getting removed when you publish.  Your user experience may be suffering if that is occurring.